# lagging when scrolling

Tags: iphone, scroll, uitabbarcontroller, core-plot, lag

I'm using core-plot in my iPhone app to display datas in plots from NSMutableArrays.
I display 10 values on the screen and I allowed horizontal scroll only like that I can see all the values when I'm scrolling.
I've got something like 100-200 values in total to load.
I use differents tabBars to handle my differents needs.

Everything works fine, but when I launch my app on the iPhone I have some monstrous laggs when scrolling. Something like 2 seconds after the graph move (on the simulator there is no laggs).
I reload graph when I shake the iPhone.
I work on a 3GS, and there is no other app running in background.

Did someone had and resolved something like that?

Do you need more info?

Comment: When you run the Time Profiler instrument against your application, where does it say the hotspot is in your code when scrolling?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question well. When I use instrument (OpenGL ES) I can see the fps, and when I'm scrolling the fps are between 10 and 15, which is very low. 
Is there something to do to build the graph better than I do? like separating tasks or something else?

Answer (score 0):

UITable (and UIScrollView) has a bug in which it causes it to call `layoutSubviews` on its parent.  Check to make sure this isn't causing your trouble.  If it is, you may be able to solve it by wrapping the table in another `UIView`.  I do this routinely to avoid this problem.

Another thing that can cause really slow scrolling is a lot of masks, transparencies, etc in your cells.  For this, you might try setting the views to rasterize, which means they'll draw themselves once into a buffer, rather than draw themselves every time.